# Trailhead : Apex Integration Services System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: unit-test, trailhead

I am working on Trailhead module for Apex Integration Services.

**Class code**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Accounts/*/contacts')
global class AccountManager {
    @HttpGet
    global static Account getAccount() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        String AccId = request.requestURI.substringBetween('/Accounts/' , '/contacts');
        Account result =  [SELECT Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = :AccId];
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Test Class Code**

```
@isTest
private class AccountManagerTest {

    private static testMethod void getAccountTest1() {
        Id recordId = createTestRecord();
        // Set up a test request
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        request.requestUri = 'https://na1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Accounts/'+ recordId +'/Contacts' ;
        request.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = request;
        // Call the method to test
        Account thisAccount = AccountManager.getAccount();
        // Verify results
        System.assert(thisAccount != null);
        System.assertEquals('Test record', thisAccount.Name);

    }

    // Helper method
    static Id createTestRecord() {
        // Create test record
        Account TestAcc = new Account(
            Name='Test record');
        insert TestAcc;
        Contact TestCon= new Contact(
            LastName='Test', 
            AccountId = Testacc.id);
        return TestAcc.Id;
    }      
}
```

I am getting error:

```
Error Message   System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Stack Trace Class.AccountManager.getAccount: line 8, column 1
Class.AccountManagerTest.getAccountTest1: line 12, column 1
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: basic idea -- output in that method via **system.debug** what is exactly **AccId**. And then play around it

Comment: Try:
        String AccId = request.requestURI.split('/')[sections.size()-2]; in AccountManager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query in this line is not returning an Account:

```
Account result =  [SELECT Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = :AccId];
```

This is happening because the variable `AccId` is null.

To get at the heart of your problem, the string method that you are using, `substringBetween()`, evaluates its parameters as case-sensitive. The `C` needs to be capitalized here:

```
String AccId = request.requestURI.substringBetween('/Accounts/' , '/Contacts');
```

---

My train of thought here was:

I've seen that error message enough to know that a query was coming back empty. My first guess was that there was no data in the test execution environment. Once I saw that you had inserted an account and that you were working with that Id, the next place I looked was how you were populating the AccId variable, since the Id of the account must not have made it into that variable. And then I saw it. You basically just have to keep tracing your way back from the line with the error message. The more you run code the easier it will get to spot the errors.

Comment: No, in trailhead module here :
https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices

URI Mapping is -  '/Accounts/<Account_ID>/contacts'

I tried with your suggestion also but no luck.

Comment: By the way, I want to how did you debug that? (I believe you have got X-Ray vision :D)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. I've seen that error message enough to know that a query was coming back empty. My first guess was that there was no data in the test execution environment. Once I saw that you had inserted an account and that you were working with that Id, the next place I looked was how you were populating the AccId variable, since the Id of the account must not have made it into that variable. And then I saw it. You basically just have to keep tracing your way back from the line with the error message. The more you run code the easier it will get to spot the errors.

Comment: You should [edit] that comment into the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error that you got but resolved it on my own by changing `Contacts` to `contacts` in the test class in the line `'https://na1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Accounts/'+ recordId +'/Contacts'`